# Starting a swing application in EDT

Tags: java, swing

I have seen two ways of starting a swing application.

Approach 1:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Approach 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

I know it is the best practice to execute swing application within EDT. Is the application executed in EDT if it started in first approach? What is the difference in these two approaches?

Comment: *" Is the application executed in EDT if it started in first approach?"* - No ... however ... since you really only need to worry about when the window becomes realised (attached to a native peer) it could be argued that it's "safe" to do so, as it's not processing any events from the EDT yet. Personally, I err on the side of caution and just do it all in the EDT :P

Comment: *it could be argued...*, swing tutorial is clear about this: **In Swing programs, the initial threads don't have a lot to do. Their most essential job is to create a Runnable object that initializes the GUI and schedule that object for execution on the event dispatch thread.**